# Powershell theming doesn't work: Set-Theme not found

Tags: powershell, themes

I tried to customize Powershell according to [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/tutorials/powerline-setup) official instruction. I did `Install-Module oh-my-posh -Scope CurrentUser` sucessfully. Doing `Import-Module oh-my-posh` returns nothing. And running `Set-Theme Paradox` gives the usual error of "Set-Theme" not being the name of commandlet etc. etc.

I use Powershell 7.1.2

What can be the reason and what can I check out? I don't know PowerShell.

Comment: See the [Windows Terminal configuration docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/get-started#:~:text=Install%20and%20set%20up%20Windows%20Terminal%201%20Installation.,7%20Command%20line%20arguments.%20...%208%20Troubleshooting) or other [articles step thrus](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27windows+terminal+themes%27&t=h_&ia=web) or [Youtube videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=windows+terminal+theme)

Comment: you can use `Get-Module -ListAvailable` to see the modules that are available to that current profile & session. you can use `Get-InstalledModule` to see the modules that you installed with one of the module installer commands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, so the syntax has changed since the time the guides were written.

```
Set-PoshPrompt Paradox
```

Comment: When I run this command, it says that the PowerShell module is no longer supported.